# Run jenkins post build step on the slave node instead of Master

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have created a Jenkins job and am able to assign it to run on the master/slave using their label name in `Restrict where this project can be run`. My job needs to do this

1. Copy test data to a target folder (not Jenkins workspace)
2. Run the test
3. Summarize results
4. Cleanup the folder with data - *Yet to be implemented*

Regarding step4, I have to delete the data before marking the job as complete. I have considered a [Conditional Build step](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) and it looks to be working in all cases except when the job is aborted.

I am considering a Post Build step using [PostBuildTask](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task)/[GroovyPostBuild](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) and it only works when the job is assigned to run on `Master`. The issue here is when I try to run the job on Slave1/Slave2, the same task doesn't seem to work and I realized that its being executed on Master instead of Slave1/2.

Would appreciate any guidance on how I can solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: With PostBuildTask Plugin, i have managed to get it to work on the same node that the job runs on. I have made postbuildtask action as the first task in the postbuild steps and that did the trick.
with GroovyPostBuild, i believe its not mindful of the node that is being used to execute the job and hence its no good to my requirement

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Post build steps run on Master by default. So, you need another plugin allow you to choose which node you want to run Post build step. In my system, I use "Flexible Publish" plugin that I see it can solve you issue

[Flexible plugin example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua8X3.png)

Comment: In my Jenkins environment, the job is assigned to a node to run. But the Post Build script is also executed on the node. But I need it to run on master. How can I do this?

Comment: @PageNotFound In your case, the Post Build script is executed on the same assigned node with build job, right? If that case, you can still use "Flexible Publish" plugin I mentioned above to choose master node in Post Build script.

Comment: Thanks @Thanh Nguyen, I will the plugin. But seems the plugin is not updated for a long time (more than 5 years)

Answer (score 0):

> > you can still use "Flexible Publish" plugin I mentioned above to choose master node in Post Build script.

It seems that the "run?" conditon (excution node) in "Flexible Publish" plugin is **not** to told the plugin where to run the Post Build script,  is to check whether the assigned node of this job is matched what you set , if true,
the Post Build script will be excuted on the assigned node.
if false , the Post Build script will **not** be excuted

for example, my job is restricted on win10 worker node , and I set  "run?" conditon (excution node) to master , the Post Build script is **not** excuted , the log is :

```
[Execution node] check if [win10] is in [[master]]
Run condition [Execution node ] preventing perform for step [[Execute scripts]]
```